# JSDOC with import/export syntax (ES modules)

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

How does one specify exported (public) properties of a module with JSDoc when using `import` and `export`?

My module structure is

```
/lib
 |- src/
 |  |- func-a.js
 |  |- func-b.js
 |- index.js
```

`lib/src/func-a.js`

```js
/** Module for queue A
 * @exports funcA/funcA
 */

/**
 * Processes A queue
 * @public
 * @param {number} n - input number
 * @returns {number} result - output number
 */
const funcA = (n) => {
  return addTwoToN(n)
}

/**
 * Adds integer two to input
 * @private
 * @param {number} n - input number
 * @returns {number} addition - input plus two
 */
const addTwoToN = (n) => n + 2

export default funcA
```

`lib/src/func-b.js`

```js
/**
 * Processes B queue
 * @public
 * @param {number} n - input number
 * @returns {number} result - output number
 */
const funcB = (n) => {
  return subtractTwoFromN(n)
}

/**
 * @private
 * @param {number} n - input number
 * @returns {number} subtraction - input minus two
 */
const subtractTwoFromN = (n) => n - 2

export default funcB
```

And finally `lib/index.js`

```js
import funcA from './src/func-a';
import funcB from './src/func-b';

/**
 * Func module
 * @module func
 */
export {
  /**
   * Queue func A
   * @module func/funcA
  */
  funcA,
  /**
    * Queue func B
    * @module func/funcB
  */
  funcB,
}
```

Now if I create some other Javascript file and do `import { funcA, funcB } from 'lib/`, it seems to pick up annotation in the editor and I'm getting intellisense which is nice.
Where I'm stuck is when trying to generate documentation via `jsdoc` CLI like so:

`jsdoc lib/index.js --destination docs/`

I end up with this:

[image: JSDOC documentation]

Which is incomplete, there's no `funcB` mentioned. When opening `funcA` link in sidebar, I only get this:

[image: JSDOC detail documentation]

There is no API documentation for that part of the library.

I am probably approaching this in a wrong way. Can I even use multiple `@module` annotations? Or should I be using `@typedef` instead?
I expected the documentation to basically show structure of the `lib/` and display the annotation for items marked with `@public` but maybe my expectation is totally different.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: If I remember correctly I had to go the other way around. The module where I'm importing some other module contains `@typedef {import('./path-to-module.js').default} ModuleName`

This would then bring `ModuleName` into the namespace. Try that.